# Failed to install cryptography in python on linux

Tags: python, pip, python-cryptography

so I am running a Linux machine with python 3.10 and the latest version of pip.

when I try installing Cryptography using PIP i get a successful installed message with one warning:

```
sh-5.1$ pip install cryptography



Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting cryptography
  Using cached cryptography-39.0.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.2 MB)
Collecting cffi>=1.12
  Using cached cffi-1.15.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (441 kB)
Collecting pycparser
  Using cached pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi, cryptography
Successfully installed cffi-1.15.1 cryptography-39.0.0 pycparser-2.21
```

However when I try verifying if it was installed correctly and try importing it I get an error:

```
sh-5.1$ python -c "import cryptography"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
sh-5.1$
```

And yes I am running the import command from the same environment where the it was installed.

the python version:

```
sh-5.1$ python --version
Python 3.10.6

sh-5.1$ type python
python is hashed (/usr/bin/python)
```

PIP Version:

```
sh-5.1$ pip --version
pip 22.3.1 from /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)

sh-5.1$ python -m pip show cryptography
WARNING: Package(s) not found: cryptography
```

Alternative method I tried as suggested:

```
sh-5.1$ python3.10 -m pip install cryptography 



Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting cryptography
  Using cached cryptography-39.0.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.2 MB)
Collecting cffi>=1.12
  Using cached cffi-1.15.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (441 kB)
Collecting pycparser
  Using cached pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi, cryptography
Successfully installed cffi-1.15.1 cryptography-39.0.0 pycparser-2.21



sh-5.1$ python -c "import cryptography"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
sh-5.1$
```

LOCATION where it is installed? :

```
python -c "import cryptography; print(cryptography.__file__)"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
```

Comment: Try: `python3 -c "import cryptography"` instead.

Comment: What does `python --version` yield?

Comment: @user56700 "sh-5.1$ python --version
Python 3.10.6"

Comment: "*I am running the import command from the same environment where the it was installed.*" How do you know? `python --version` ? `type python` ? `pip --version` ? `python -m pip show cryptography`

Comment: Alternatively, try `python3.10 -m pip install cryptography` to be sure.

Comment: @user56700 i tried almost everything and provided all the error msgs

Comment: `pip show cryptography` "*WARNING: Package(s) not found: cryptography*" This is the key part — `cryptography` was not installed despite `pip` reported it installed all packages. Thing that puzzled me most: `cryptography-39.0.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl` is a wheel for Python 3.6 so `pip` for Python 3.10 cannot install it. Try running `pip cache list` and then `pip remove` to remove the wheel from the cache, then install it again. Try to install it without cache at all using `pip install --no-cache-dir --no-deps`

Comment: `pip remove` -> `pip cache remove`. My bad, sorry.